# React Native bridging to swift native class not working

Tags: ios, swift, typescript, react-native

We upgraded React Native from "^0.62.2" to "0.66.0". Before the Bridges worked fine. After using the latest version, i can't get even the [basic tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) running.

**CalendarManager.swift**

```
@objc(CalendarManager)
class CalendarManager: NSObject {
    
    @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool { return true }
    
    @objc(addEvent:location:date:)
    func addEvent(_ name: String, location: String, date: NSNumber) -> Void {   // Date is ready to use!
        print("")
    }
    
    @objc
    func constantsToExport() -> [String: Any]! {
        return ["someKey": "someValue"]
    }
}
```

**CalendarManager.m**

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CalendarManager, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(nonnull NSNumber *)date)

@end
```

***And in React Native CalendardModule.ts***

```
const { CalendarModule } = NativeModules;

type CalendarManager = {
  createCalendarEvent(name: string, location: string): void;
};

export default CalendarModule as CalendarManager;
```

So  when i call

```
//some callback function
 const onClickListenerHandler = () => {
    console.log("Test");

    CalendarModule.createCalendarEvent("Test", "Test");
  };
```

I can see the "Test" log entry but nothing more. When debugging into the native code, the debugger won't hit the breakpoint in the swift class.

If i create an init method in CalendarManager.swift, it won't even get called.

What am i doing wrong?